# @WithUserDetails does not seem to work

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-social, spring-boot-test

I have an application in which I use Spring Social Security for authentication and authorization. Unfortunately I am having some problems with mocking Spring Security. It seems that it does not work at all.

I have a REST controller that returns 404 Not Found if the identifier of the entity it should return is not available. If the user is not logged in then any page redirects to the social login page of my app.

I have read [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/test-method.html) that the `@WithUserDetails` annotation would suit me the best.

So my test method looks like this

```java
@Test
@SqlGroup({
    @Sql(executionPhase = ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD, statements = "INSERT INTO UserAccount(id, creationtime, modificationtime, version, email, firstname, lastname, role, signinprovider) VALUES (1, '2008-08-08 20:08:08', '2008-08-08 20:08:08', 1, 'user', 'John', 'Doe', 'ROLE_USER', 'FACEBOOK')"), })
@Rollback
@WithUserDetails
public void ifNoTeamsInTheDatabaseThenTheRestControllerShouldReturnNotFoundHttpStatus() {
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity("/getTeamHistory/{team}", String.class, "Team");
    Assert.assertEquals(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, response.getStatusCode());
}
```

But this does not seem to work at all. It looks like the test method is executed with anonymous user, because the status I get is 200 OK.

My test class is annotated like this

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@Transactional
public class TeamRestControllerTest {
    //...
}
```

Has anyone ever experienced such an issue with mocking Spring Security that is delivered by Spring Social?

Comment: And it works as expected... It fills a `SecurityContext` on a `ThreadLocal` with a default setting. Next you are issuing a HTTP request to a server, the request executes on a new thread. Basically `@WithUserDetails` and others work for unit tests and integration test on the service layer, where you directly call methods. It won't work for system integration tests where you are calling a remote server. I suspect it would work if you use `@@WebMvcTest` instead of `SpringBootTest` which turns it into a full system test.

Comment: `@WebMvcTest` does not suit me as it does not load my contexts. I have however tried with `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` and then an autowired `MockMvc` instance. It seems to be working flawlessly with `@SpringBootTest` and `@WithUserDetails`. I will answer my own question once I do my tests.

Comment: EHrm... What you are doing manually is basically what `@WebMvcTest` is doing. `MockMvc` is still calling an internal representation and not the started application, I would say that at the moment you are starting to much and only use a part.

Comment: Hmmm, when I use only `@WebMvcTest` then I have to mock each and every single thing with `@MockBean` or specify my contexts manually for `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` which now is deprecated anyways. With `@SpringBootTest` I get this stuff for free.

Comment: You shouldn't need that if you do `@WebMvcTest(YourController)` that should happen for you, spring boot will detect what is needed.

Comment: Unfortunately not, because I have a `@ControllerAdvice` annotated class that of course is tried to be created, because it applies to every controller I have. This class has some `@Autowired` dependencies. If I use `@WebMvcTest` then it fails, because this stuff is not loading all of the contexts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm unable to test it at the moment, but here's a *possible* solution.

Looking at @WithUserDetails implementation:

```
@WithSecurityContext(factory = WithUserDetailsSecurityContextFactory.class)
public @interface WithUserDetails {
    ...
}

final class WithUserDetailsSecurityContextFactory implements
        WithSecurityContextFactory<WithUserDetails> {

    private BeanFactory beans;

    @Autowired
    public WithUserDetailsSecurityContextFactory(BeanFactory beans) {
        this.beans = beans;
    }

    public SecurityContext createSecurityContext(WithUserDetails withUser) {
        String beanName = withUser.userDetailsServiceBeanName();
        UserDetailsService userDetailsService = StringUtils.hasLength(beanName)
                ? this.beans.getBean(beanName, UserDetailsService.class)
                : this.beans.getBean(UserDetailsService.class);
        String username = withUser.value();
        Assert.hasLength(username, "value() must be non empty String");
        UserDetails principal = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                principal, principal.getPassword(), principal.getAuthorities());
        SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
        context.setAuthentication(authentication);
        return context;
    }
}
```

You could create the Security Context of your choice following the same pattern:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@Documented
@WithSecurityContext(factory = WithoutUserFactory.class)
public @interface WithoutUser {
}

public class WithoutUserFactory implements WithSecurityContextFactory<WithoutUser> {
    public SecurityContext createSecurityContext(WithoutUser withoutUser) {
        return SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
    }
}
```

The other available annotations: `WithAnonymousUser`, `WithMockUser`, `WithSecurityContext` (and `WithUserDetails`)

Answer (score 0):

Adding my workaround, probably it can be helpful for someone else.

I think I met the same problem:

- A `@Testcontainers` (for PostgreSQL DB emulation) + `@SpringBootTest` test.
- Mocked the `SecurityContext` via annotation with `@WithSecurityContext` with mocking `factory`.
- I need this mocking for an Envers `RevisionListener`, where I get the userName and userId from the `SecurityContext` created normally by Keycloak.
- When calling the Spring beans in the test, mocking works ok.
- But when calling the API via `TestRestTemplate`, `SecurityContext` is not mocked and is returning a `null` for all fields (principal, etc).

The original class looks like this:

```java
@SpringBootTest(
    classes = SpringBootInitializer.class,
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
    properties = {"keycloak.enabled=false"}
)
@ContextConfiguration(
    classes = PersistenceConfiguration.class,
    initializers = MyTest.Initializer.class
)
// !!! the SecurityContext mocking will NOT work when calling the controller via REST
@MockKeycloakUser() // do not fail on getting Keycloak data in UserDataRevisionListener
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class, ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class }) // turn off Spring Security to avoid 401 and 302 responses
@Testcontainers // required to fill @Container fields with containers
@Log4j2
@ActiveProfiles("integration-test")
class MyTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    // ...

    // call via restTemplate looks like this
    private List<MyDTO> executeSearchQuery(String query) {
        String searchUrl = getSearchUrl(port, query, filter);
        MyDTO[] results = this.restTemplate.getForObject(searchUrl, MyDTO[].class);
        return List.of(results);
    }

    // ...
}
```

What I used to make the `SecurityContext` work is:

- Add the `MockMvc` field to the test class.
- Add `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` on the test class.
- **!!!** Execute the API via `MockMvc` instead of `TestRestTemplate`

Looks like this:

```java
// all other annotations on the test class stay the same

@AutoConfigureMockMvc // make MockMvc work
// ...
class MyTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc; // trick to make the mock SecurityContext work, which does not work when calling via TestRestTemplate

    // Execute the API via mockMvc looks like this:
    private String getApiResponse(MyRequest request, int expectedHttpStatus) {
        final String url = getRequestUrl();

        final String requestBody = JacksonUtils.serializeToString(request);

        try {
            final MockHttpServletRequestBuilder builder = MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .post(url)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(requestBody)
            ;

            // use MockMvc instead of TestRestTemplate to successfully use the mock user emulation
            return mockMvc
                .perform(builder)
                .andExpect(status().is(expectedHttpStatus))
                .andReturn()
                .getResponse()
                .getContentAsString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```