# Unit Test Java API/Http requests

Tags: java, spring, spring-test

I've have built a Java API that at the moment can add an entry to a H2 Database and retrieve all entries. I've build the app based on this tutorial: http://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-crud-rest-service-with-jpa-hibernate

This is the code that I have written:

Offer.java

```
package com.java.api.offers.SpringBootOffers.Offer;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Offer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue

private int id;
private String description;
private int price;

public Offer(){
    super();
}

public Offer(int id, String description, int price) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.description = description;
    this.price = price;
}

public int getId(){
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id){
    this.id = id;
}

public String getDescription(){
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String desc){
    this.description = desc;
}

public int getPrice(){
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(int price){
    this.price = price;
}
}
```

OfferController.java

```
package com.java.api.offers.SpringBootOffers.Offer;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class OfferController {

@Autowired
private OfferRepository offerRepository;

@GetMapping("/offers")
public List<Offer> getAllOffers() {
    return offerRepository.findAll();
}


@PostMapping("/offers")
public ResponseEntity<Object> createStudent(@RequestBody Offer offer) {
    Offer savedOffer = offerRepository.save(offer);

    URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}")
            .buildAndExpand(savedOffer.getId()).toUri();

    return ResponseEntity.created(location).build();

}

}
```

OfferRepository.java

```
package com.java.api.offers.SpringBootOffers.Offer;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface OfferRepository extends JpaRepository<Offer, Long> {};
```

And I am trying to now unit test the GET and POST method, however I'm unsure as to how it works. I have written the following test:

```
package com.java.api.offers.SpringBootOffers;

import com.java.api.offers.SpringBootOffers.Offer.Offer;
import com.java.api.offers.SpringBootOffers.Offer.OfferController;
import com.java.api.offers.SpringBootOffers.Offer.OfferRepository;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;



import java.io.IOException;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = OfferController.class)
public class SpringBootOffersApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private OfferRepository offerRepository;

    @Test
    public void getAllOffers() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

        Offer offer = new Offer();
        HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8080/offers");

        HttpResponse httpResponse = HttpClientBuilder.create().build().execute(request);

        Assertions.assertThat(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.SC_NOT_FOUND);
    }

}
```

which is failing with following error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'offerController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'offerRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.java.api.offers.SpringBootOffers.Offer.OfferRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:586)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:572)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:139)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.java.api.offers.SpringBootOffers.Offer.OfferRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1101)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:583)
    ... 43 more
```

I'm rather new to Java so still trying to figure out how to test the API, so could anyone help with the above error message, or help in general with how to correctly test http methods in java.

Thanks!

Comment: The webmvc test will only load the slice of the context required to test the controller. Instead of autowiring the repository replace it with a `@MockBean` a mocked object will be used instead and you can control responses with the mockito APIs

Comment: Have you tried `@DataJpaTest`?

Comment: @DarrenForsythe thanks, that has passed the test. So, going forward, in order to control the responses, just add a mocked object with the POST test? Thanks,

Comment: WIth an WebMvcTest yes, you should (generally) just mock the dependencies you require. You can load other beans/configurations if its too much work effort and mock at a lower level or use test beans that return hardcoded instead responses too

Comment: Here is explained well about your case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40064988/cant-autowire-jparepository-in-junit-test-spring-boot-application

Comment: thats really helpful, thank you @PankajPatel

Comment: @LewMoore I changed my answer based on good comments, and changed your test source from apache http to Spring way.

Answer (score 3):

I changed the answer based on @DarranForsythe comment, and changed your test source code to Spring way.

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = OfferController.class)
public class SpringBootOffersApplicationTests {

    @MockBean
    private OfferRepository offerRepository;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception
    {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void getAllOffers() throws Exception {

        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/offers"))
            .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful())
            .andDo(print());
    }
}
```